# React Typescript Component Unexpected token, expected "{"

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, compiler-errors

I have a react app in typescript that cant compile for unknown reasons. This is the error I get:

```
./src/App.tsx
SyntaxError: C:\Users\LANAUS\repos\gdn-tabular-app\src\src\App.tsx: Unexpected token, expected "{" (12:34)

  10 | 
  11 | // Web socket client connection
> 12 | export class App extends Component<any, any> {
     |                                   ^
  13 |     index = 0
  14 |     connections: httpLib.ClientRequest[];
  15 |     tlm: AxiosInstance;
```

I cant figure out why it seems to have an issue with <any, any> being in the class definition. From what I can tell it looks like it is applying JS rules to my TSX file. As a test, when I removed <any, any> then the error became:

```
./src/App.tsx
SyntaxError: C:\Users\LANAUS\repos\gdn-tabular-app\src\src\App.tsx: Unexpected token (14:15)

  12 | export class App extends Component {
  13 |     index = 0
> 14 |     connections: httpLib.ClientRequest[];
```

I am at a total loss here, does anyone know why this is failing to compile?

Additional Relevent Files:

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx",
            {
                "runtime": "automatic"
            },
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
        ]
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the typescript plugin for babel?

Comment: @FelixKling if you are refering to @babel/preset-typescript, I have tried it and it causes npm start to freeze on ```Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...```

Comment: I can't comment on that, I can only say that if you want babel to understand typescript code you need to load the appropriate plugin (just like you do for JSX). Or you can compile the Typescript files to JS files first, directly with the Typescript compiler.

Comment: Are you also using WebPack? And which is the configuration file? Also which command are you using to run the project? About the problem, as @FelixKling mentioned your should have the @babel/preset-typescript and in this case the question should be why is it freezen with the message above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't listen to past me, past me was 2 weeks into this problem and couldn't think straight. Felix Kling had it right, I needed the babel preset (@babel/preset-typescript) in my .babelrc.

The reason it seemed to freeze on `Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...` message is because the app was running and if I had checked my browser I would have seen the app. Something I did must have suppressed the warnings I usually see after this message.